# show html email template element only when variable value is not null/undefined/empty

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, templates, mailgun

I am using mailgun for email and using html as template in node.js. I want to show html tags only when variable is valid.

Below is my function where i am replacing variable value.

```
exports.sendParentReservation = async function(data) {
   let template = await loadTemplate(parentReservation);
   let embeddedLogo = await loadLogo();

   // > PARENT DATA: parent name, kid name, service name, company name, group name, reservation date,price

   template = template.replace(/{{action_url}}/g, parentReservationsLink);
   template = template.replace(/{{parent_name}}/g, data.parentName);
   template = template.replace(/{{nextStep}}/g, data.nextStep);

   mailer.sendMail({
    from: '...',
    to: data.recipient,
    subject: "Your reservation on ...",
    html: template,
    attachments: [{
        cid: 'logo.png',
        content: embeddedLogo,
        encoding: 'base64'
    }],
   }, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err}`);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Mailgun Response: " + JSON.stringify(info,null,4));
    }
 });
};
```

Below is my html email template code

```
<table class="attributes" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
    <tr>
        <td class="attributes_content">
          <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
            <tr>
             <td class="attributes_item"><span class="f-fallback"><strong>Instructions - Next/Steps</strong></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td class="attributes_item">{{nextStep}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```

I want to hide all these above html code if `nextStep` is `null/undefined or empty`.

Below is screenshot of my email template i highlighted the section i want to hide in screenshot.
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to do this:

```
 <script>
      if (nextStep != null) {
      document.write('<table class="attributes" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">    <tr>        <td class="attributes_content">          <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">            <tr>             <td class="attributes_item"><span class="f-fallback"><strong>Instructions - Next/Steps</strong></span></td>            </tr>            <tr>              <td class="attributes_item">{{nextStep}}</td>            </tr>          </table>        </td>    </tr> </table>') 
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do this like adding dynamic css class to hide or If condition inside html?

Comment: if you're using `ejs` as a front-end framework, you can do this much easier. I can edit my answer if you are, but if not, I am not sure of any other way, this in my opinion is an okay work around

Comment: You can see in function I am replacing it. So how can I access nextStep in html file.